# plot several plots that can be toggled

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this code:

```
def PlotCategories(data_frame, column_name):
    data_frame[column_name].value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind='bar', title=column_name, rot=0)
    plt.show(0)

PlotCategories(df, 'x')
PlotCategories(df, 'y')

plt.show()
```

Tried a few variants of it. I would like to create one plot window where I can click through the 2 plots (toggle) as I am used to from R. Can I achieve this? How can I adjust the above? Thanks!